# Nested require() Can't Find Function Definition in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, require

I have lots of files to require() and found out that some of them are required too often so made a 'relay' object like this:

```
[../somePath/include.js] and include1, include2, ...
function f() { console.log("I'm a function"); }
module.exports = { f };
```

```
[relay.js]
const inc = require('../somePath/include');
const inc1 = require('../somePath/include1');
const inc2 = require('../somePath/include2');
...
const fib = inc.f;
module.exports = { fib };
```

```
[server.js]
const fib = require('relay').fib;  // fib is undefined
// const fib = require('../somePath/include').f;  //OK
let x = fib(); //TypeError: fib is not a function
```

And this gives me TypeError: fib is not a function.

I'm quite sure there's no typo because Visual Studio Intellisense finds the definition (F12) without any problem. Also, it says f *is* a function. It is also possible to traverse definitions f and fib by pressing F12 multiple times.

What am I missing? Is this something related to ES6 stuff like object destructuring?

Answer (score 0):

Found a cycle.

One of the includes was located in a folder different from others so I falsely referenced relay.js there, so a require **cycle** was made.